# Run JS in WebView from Java android

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I can trigger Android method from JS (using addJavascriptInterface), but can I trigger JavaScript in my WebView from Java?

Comment: Thank you for all yours replies. I will accept the fastest, although all were very helpful and I took sth from everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do `loadUrl("javascript:{javascript statement}");`. Try that and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can:

```
webview.loadUrl("javascript:alert('wowzer');");
```

you can chain lines of javascript as you please ensure you have:

```
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have `Webview webView;` initialized, you can simply

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:functionName()");
```

to call `functionName()` within the current page (assuming that page has javascript with functionName() loaded).